# Passing arrays using json?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have this php code

```
   $ids = array(1,2,3);
   $names = array("cat","elephant","cow"); 
   $originalSettings = array ('ids'=>$ids,'names'=>$names);
   $jsonSettings = json_encode($originalSettings);
   echo $jsonSettings;
```

and this is the jQuery code

```
$.post("ajax.php", {},
function(data){
data.ids.each(function(i) {
alert(data.names[i]);
}
//is it possible to receive the arrays and navigate them   
}, "json");
```

How can I pass arrays using json and receive them in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: You have a bracket missing after your alert( call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function(data) {
    $.each(data.array1, function(i) {
        alert(data.array2[i]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works, it is slightly different $.each(data.array1,function(i){alert(data.array2[i]);});